# Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"].ToString() is not working in IE11

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-11

I have a basic page that is hooked into a third-party website internally. When a button is clicked on this third-party webpage, my webpage is launched in another tab.

When launched, I capture the previous page URL so I can get certain ID in the previous URL. This has been working fine on IE8 through to IE10.
But IE 11 will not return the full URL at all. Is there a quick fix anyone know of?

i have tried all the below with out any joy,

```
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"].ToString()
ViewState["PreviousPageURL"] = Request.UrlReferrer;
Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
string urlName = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);
```

Appreciate any help in advance.
Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Do not trust the client - you should not depend upon the `Referer` header being sent or being correct.

In particular, Google Search uses a JavaScript trick to prevent the `Referer` header being sent from search result pages - webmasters can no-longer get the original Google search page address (to extract the search-terms from the querystring) - ostensibly this is to protect users privacy.

Other reasons include:

- A user's custom privacy settings to disable the header
- Third-party security software (like Norton Internet Security) that disables the header
- Network security hardware, such as HTTP proxies or corporate firewalls, that block the header
- A browser extension

To my knowledge, IE11 does not change `Referer`-handling behaviour.

In the code examples you gave, the last 4 examples all use `Request.Urlreferrer` so of course they're all going to return the same result.

Comment: thanks for the feed back but is there a fix or helpfull code i can use to achive what i need, googling around i find the same answer but no solution or fix.

Answer (score 0):

from my experience, if you open the page in an iframe, the referer field won't be empty in ie (at least not in ie11)